# How to get the file URL from absolute path in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, file, url, path, delphi-2009

I'm looking for a Delphi function which returns the file URL path from the Windows path. Is there something for it built-in in Delphi ?

Example:

```
Input
C:\Users\Documents\File.txt

Output
file:///C:/Users/Documents/File.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`UrlCreateFromPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773773%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API function.
Here is the example:

```
uses
  ComObj, WinInet, ShLwApi;

function FilePathToURL(const FilePath: string): string;
var
  BufferLen: DWORD;
begin
  BufferLen := INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH;
  SetLength(Result, BufferLen);
  OleCheck(UrlCreateFromPath(PChar(FilePath), PChar(Result), @BufferLen, 0));
  SetLength(Result, BufferLen);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(FilePathToURL('C:\Users\Documents\File.txt'));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I can see you with Remy Lebeau suggested the same function. May I ask you, should the FilePath from the function's parameter exist or the UrlCreateFromPath function works with it as with a plain string ?

Comment: The [`UrlCreateFromPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773773%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) takes the input path as a string so it doesn't matter if the target path actually exists.

Answer (score 8):

Look at [`UrlCreateFromPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773773(v=vs.85).aspx). Note that there are caveats with the [`file:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) scheme, though.  It is not stanardized across platforms.  There are multiple formats to represent the same path in different ways, even just under Windows.  Since IE4, the Win32 API standardizes on a single format, but other formats still exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response. About the file scheme, does it mean that the result from the UrlCreateFromPath function may differ and depends on installed Interner Explorer ? I hope no one has IE4 at this time, but I need to rely on this function.

Comment: `UrlCreateFromPath()` was introduced in IE5 on Win98SE and Win2K. Microsoft standardized its use of the `file:` scheme in IE4.  As long as you are passing around your URL to just Shell APIs, you should be fine.