# Using UrlCreateFromPath in delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, url, converters

I find the next function code in stackoverflow.
When I try convert a file such as: 'C:\teste.zip' to URL format the resulting string contains extra trailing #0 char. My result is something as ' 'file:///C:/teste.zip#0'
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance, Luiz

```
function FilePathToURL(const FilePath: string): string;
var
  Buffer: string;
  BufferSize: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  BufferSize := Length('file:///' + FilePath + #0);
  SetLength(Buffer, BufferSize);

  if UrlCreateFromPath(PChar(FilePath), PChar(Buffer), @BufferSize, 0) = S_OK then
    Result := Buffer;
end;
```

Comment: You need to do `SetLength(Buffer, BufferSize)` again.

Comment: Sorry, that was [`my fault`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8497976/960757). It was terribly written. What I'm still not sure is whether the reference contains a typo and wanted to mention the maximum length `INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH` for the `pszUrl` rather than `pszPath` (which should be at most `MAX_PATH` long).

Comment: Thank you, It solved my problem. I just add SetLength(Buffer, BufferSize) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating expected `BufferSize` in a wrong way. According to [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), maximum expected length is `INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH`.

Proper code for converting Path to Url would be:

```
const
  INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH = 2048 + 32 + 3;

function FilePathToURL(const FilePath: string): string;
var
  Buffer: array [0.. INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH - 1] of Char;
  BufferSize: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  BufferSize := INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH;
  if UrlCreateFromPath(PChar(FilePath), @Buffer, @BufferSize, 0) = S_OK then
    Result := Buffer;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, your code also returns the correct result and it is simpler. Thanks

Comment: Your buffer size is off by one. You tell the API that it's smaller than it really is.

Comment: I edited the answer to correct the error that Rob pointed out. The error was benign, but it is clearer this way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. My Windows skills are getting rusty.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine, I just tested ok:

```
function FilePathToURL(const FilePath: string): string;
var
  Buffer: string;
  BufferSize: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  BufferSize := Length('file:///' + FilePath + #0);
  SetLength(Buffer, BufferSize);

  if UrlCreateFromPath(PChar(FilePath), PChar(Buffer), @BufferSize, 0) = S_OK then
    Result := Buffer;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add(FilePathToURL(Edit1.Text));
end;
```

maybe if you post your complete code, how you are calling the function...

Comment: Hi, in XE7 if I use the code above the result of FilePathToURL contains a extra #0 char. I am putiing the result string in Richedit control with something as: RichEdit.SelText:=FilePathToURL('c:\test.zip')+ '  received; but t was being truncated because  FilePathToURL('c:\test.zip') returns a extra trailing #0 char on result.